# Show selected images

Tags: javascript, php

I am working on a functionality in PHP where there are many photos which user can see , Now user can select some photos and click on button called proceed .

**Issue :-**

My issue is after the click of that proceed button , on the next screen the selected photos should be seen selected photos .

How should I approach this ? It will be helpful if you give me some example of some code .

Here is code I am using for selecting images ,

```
$instagram_url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token=297947523.32f60ec&count=-1';

$instagram_json = file_get_contents($instagram_url);
$instagram_array = json_decode($instagram_json,true);
if(!empty($instagram_array)){
    foreach($instagram_array['data'] as $image){

        echo'<input id="imageId" type="image" src="'.$image['images']['low_resolution']['url'].'" onclick="mark(this)" hspace="20" vspace="20"/>';
    }
```

I want to do it with Array .

Comment: are the imgs you are getting are stored in the database ?

Comment: @Laith, Nope , It will be helpful if it is done with array , Also I am adding this in question.

Comment: Edited the question @Laith

Comment: ok man i will check it back

Comment: Mhm you are using json right ? if yes you should tag json , i really dont know json. im sorry buddy .

Comment: @Laith .. Yes Json .. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

U can place selected photos to PHP save in the SESSION and output on the next page from session, or Database. I think More good use SESSION

```
$_SESSION['selected_photos'] = $_POST['selected_photos'];
```

On the next page

```
for($i=0; $i<size($_SESSION['selected_photos']; $i++){
    print "<img src='...' .../>";
}
```

Comment: Hi @andrew z , Thanks for your answer , Can I do it with array ? till now , I was working with mobile where we use to do it , I am a noob in web development .

Comment: Sure u can do this

Comment: I will be thankful if you tell me how to do it . Also I have added some more info in question..